# Translate FQDN to IP address in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I'd like to add an FQDN to our DNS server to resolve to a specific IP address.
For example:  (company-data) should resolve to 192.168.1.1

This works when I add it to the Windows host file, but I'd like to add it in DNS for all users to access.

I don't want to create A record in my local domain, as the users should only be able to browse to http:// company-data without including our local domain details.

I've tried creating a new zone (company-data) and adding an A record with a blank name (use parent domain name if blank), but it doesn't work when browsing or pinging (company-data)

However, when I create an A record "www" pointing to 192.168.1.1 in zone company-data,
I can ping www.company-data no problem.

How can I get rid of the "www"?

Comment: If you create an A record within the domain, they don't need the domain name itself if they're joined to that domain.

Answer (score 1):

The fast solution is to add an A record in your local domain - your users will be able to browse to `http://company-data` without including your local domain. The default behavior of Windows machines is to lookup single-label names in their local domain.

The full solution is to configure GlobalNames zone on Windows Server 2008 DNS Server. For details see this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc816610(v=ws.10).aspx).